# How to make a letter black in illustrator when editing from a whole letter to a section of one

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-design

I started with the full letter S and wanted to split it into three but when getting just the middle part no matter how I do it (with scissors, closing the end with pen, deleting anchors then moving the ends down ect) I always end up with the image below:

[image: section of letter s with white segment through it]

Is there a way to make the middle segment of the S fully black? I am using an opensourced font that I am editing in illustrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the left there's an outlined S and 2 red lines:

[image]

**One line at a time**: Select the line and apply Object > Path > Divide Objects Below.

In the right both divisions are done, the result is ungrouped and the unwanted slices are moved a little to show they are now separate.

I guess your attempts are failed because you have not succeeded to make a single closed shape, but that's already said by others.

Answer (score 0):

Type glyphs are **compound shapes** when outlines are created.

Compound shapes mean that overlapping parts become "holes" or reversed out of the main shape.

**Release the compound path** via `Object > Compound Path > Release` then the shape will behave like all standard shapes.

---

Or.. select all the parts and click the `Unite` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

---

Although it somewhat appears as though you have two **open paths** there, not a single closed shape. Use the **Selection Tool** (black arrow) to select both parts, then choose `Object > Path > Join` twice. The first join will connect the two parts, the second join will close the path creating a closed shape.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, sadly this didn't work. I tried it on the multiple ways I had made the segment.